# How to cancel NSMenu tracking when pressing any key?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I am displaying a popupmenu that shows LDAP entries dynamically.

I noticed that pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> key causes the NSMenu to cancel tracking.

How can I achieve this behaviour while pressing any other key (not just <kbd>ESC</kbd>)?